# Unable to load MKMapView in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to display some location in MKMapView. While loading the mapViewController, I am getting the following error message in console.

> __GEORegisterNetworkDefaults_block_invoke_0: Could not connect to geod on com.apple.geod.defaults

I am using xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1 for my application.

I am using the following code to show the address:

```
- (void) showAddress 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span = span;
    region.center = location;
}
```

And for getting the address location from following code.

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation 
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [@"cupertino" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSError *err;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) 
    {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}
```

When I google about the mapkit tutorials then I found the above code from http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

Does anyone know why I am getting the above error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you told XCode that your app requires access to location information? I think it's 'privileges' or something similar in the project config.

Comment: I didn't get anything like 'privileges' or similar in the project config.